# Determine if a send is a triggered send

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, triggered-send

is there a way to determine if a send is a triggered send? I see that with the personalization string `%%_IsTestSend%%` I can determine if a send is a test, is there something similar for triggered sends? I'd like to add jobID to the utm_campaign of my marketing blast emails when the email isn't a triggered send or a test send. Something like this:

```
%%[
    if _isTestSend == false OR [_isTriggeredSend???] == false then
        ... // this code will not run for test sends or triggered sends
    endif
]%%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the Personalization String **_JobSubscriberBatchID** will help. You should check wether the value is different when it is a triggered send or user-initiated.

As quoted from Marketing Cloud help:
This value ties a Triggered Send Job or a Subscriber Key Send Job to a Subscriber and a BatchID.

You can find all personalization strings [here](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/strings/)

Please let me know if this helped

Comment: Thanks for the reply Wesley, so I sent a user initiated email and a triggered email with the _JobSubscriberBatchID outputted to the html, and they both gave a value of 1. So I don't think I can use this to determine if the email is a triggered send. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You could remove the code from the e-mails which are used for triggered sends. That would be the easiest way I think

Comment: Hey Wesley, I get your point, I am trying to avoid that though because I have an @UrlVariables variable that is set in a content block that handles the logic for any url variable that is shared across all my emails. I'd love to be able to add logic there to handle this and not have to edit all my transactional / lifecycle / journey builder emails. I'll let this question live a bit longer to see if maybe someone else has an idea. Thanks for the help so far.